# How to Read/Write file from hard disk in firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Well, greasemonkey is simply great but it cant read/write files from hard disk for security reasons...
so, whats are the other ways to read/write files from hard disk in firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find most of what you need to get started with file I/O in a Firefox extension here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO